# Left censored regression bounded at zero

Tags: zero-inflation, tobit-regression, truncated-distributions

I've been handed some data that is obviously left-censored. Many zeroes, probably due to insensitivity of the assay. However, since it is a protein level assay, it is theoretically impossible for any result to actually be less than zero. Thus, the data is both censored at "zero" and bounded at true zero. I seem to recall that Tobit regression can predict negative values, meaning it isn't for me. Fortunately it's otherwise a very simple regression, one response, one predictor. What should I look into?

Comment: Ask about the actual censoring levels.  Sometimes, absent any information, you can infer them (at least approximately) by examining the smallest uncensored value.  It gets more complicated when the censoring levels can vary appreciably.

Comment: Are the censored data the predictor or the response? How many data points are there?

Comment: Your question is kinda vague to me. Do you have zero inflated data that you are trying to model? Could you show us the histogram of your data? Are the non zero values, positive and continuous or positive and integer? If you give me these information I think I can help you.

Comment: It's a protein assay--an ELISA, so the non-zero data is continuous. It is physically impossible for there to be less than no protein, so any method that presumed some kind of "continuation" beyond zero would be absurd. What is more annoying is that the materials assayed also cannot actually have zero amounts of the protein, since it's from transgenic animals. So there could be a sensitivity issue for the assay. As I said, the data was handed to me.

Comment: Ways to handle left-censored data differ depending on whether they are the outcomes/responses or predictors in a model. For example, are you trying to distinguish ELISA-based protein levels (outcomes) between genotypes? Or do you want to use protein levels to predict something like survival? Please clarify that by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.